# nginx proxy_pass remote ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

I have one domain and two aws instances, what nginx conf should be for next case ... - when user goes to 'example.com/instance2' (proxied by first instance's nginx) it should get data from remote ip (second instance public ip)

Now I have

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1337;
}

location /blog/admin/ {
    proxy_pass http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:80;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

but when I go to `example.com/blog/admin/` I get

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

## Update

```
location ~ /blog/admin(?<section>.*) {
    proxy_pass http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:80$section;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}
```

but when on second instance redirect was fired to `http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX/login`  - I got `blabla.com/login` too, but it should be `blabla.com/blog/admin/login`

Comment: Does `http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:80/blog/admin/` return what is expected?

Comment: @Vasfed `http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:80` returns what expected ... I need data simply from `/` (remote XX.XX.XXX.XXX) on `blablablabla.com/blog/admin/`

Comment: You are essentially rewriting URLs as well. See http://serverfault.com/questions/586586/nginx-redirect-via-proxy-rewrite-and-preserve-url for example

Comment: @DenisMysenko yes I've found it yesterday ... look at my update ^

Comment: You have to note that your HTML content may contain links, and those links ARE NOT modified. So if your XX.XX.XXX.XXX site has a /login link - it will stay /login, it won't magically become /blog/admin/login. The only way to alter the HTML content out of box is this filter: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html